# QGIS Composer Distorted SVG PDF Output

Tags: qgis, vector, printing, pdf, svg

I've noticed that some SVGs are distorted when outputting to a vector PDF from QGIS.  A good example is NorthArrow_07.svg.

The image on the left is how it looks in the composer and the image on the right is the PDF output.

[image: QGIS SVG Issue]

I have tried increasing the composer DPI but it has no effect.  Is there a setting that causes this distortion?  I need vector output - not raster.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why that is getting distorted but a workaround is to **print it as a raster** in the *Composition* menu > *Export settings*:

[image: Print as raster]

This seems to fix the distortion:

[image: pdf]

**EDIT**:

Locate the svg file in your QGIS directory (something like `.../apps/qgis/svg/arrows`, open it up and save the image as a png. Then use the png in your Print Composer. When exporting to pdf without the *Print to raster* setting enabled, there should not be a distortion but you may see some degredation in the quality of the image depending on the size.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of this but I need vector output.  Question amended.

Comment: @Damien - Edited post.

Comment: I appreciate the workaround but I need 100% vector output.  This simple symbol was just an example.  My actual maps are full of symbols.  I'm trying to eliminate the need for Adobe Illustrator in my day-to-day cartography and QGIS is *almost* there.  Falling back to raster is a bit of a hack in the CAD/GIS world.

Comment: @Damien - No problem buddy! Only other alternative I can think of is to **Export as Image** and then use an image-to-pdf converter. Feel free to send a [bug report](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis).